# Understanding $S^{2}\times S^{1}$ as a reduction of $SU(2)\times U(1)$ by $U(1)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, topological-groups, geometric-topology

I'm trying to undersand the topology of $S^{2}\times S^{1}$ as a result of reduction of $G=SU(2)\times U(1)$ by an $H=U(1)$ subgroup, in other words as: $\frac{SU(2)\times U(1)}{U(1)}$.

I know elements of $G$ can be written as $\left(U,z\right)$ with $U$ an element of $SU(2)$ and $z$ a unit complex number. If we take $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ then we have a homomorphism $\phi_{a,b}:U(1)\rightarrow G$ of the form:

$$\phi_{a,b}\left(z\right)=\left(diag\left(z^{b},z^{-b}\right)z^{a}\right)$$ which is injective when $a,b$ are coprime and then the image $H_{a,b}\leq G$. (Any injective homomorphism $\varphi:U(1)\rightarrow G$ is conjugate to some $\varphi_{p,q}$, as its projection to the $SU(2)$-factor may be conjugated to land in the standard maximal torus.)

If I'm understanding this correctly for $a=1$ we simply get $S^{3}$ as our $G/H_{a,b}$ topology (as in electroweak symmetry breaking in the standard model of particle physics). If $b=1$,we get a class of lens spaces (one for each a, the three sphere here being counted as a degenerate lens space)

I'm thinking $S^{2}\times S^{1}$ corresponds to $b=0$. How do I then understand what the different $a$ correspond to (especially in light of $\pi_{1}\left(G/H_{a,b}\right)=\mathbb{Z}/a$ for $a\neq1$)? Note I'm following a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.05623.pdf).

I'm ultimately interested in the connected sum:$$\#_{k}S^{2}\times S^{1}=\#_{k}\frac{SU(2)\times U(1)}{U(1)}$$

and how I would proceed with a similar breakdown hence me wanting to understand what's going on in the trivial case first.

Comment: $a = 0$ corresponds to $S^2\times S^1$ while $b = 0$ corresponds to $S^3$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese. The paper I reference above seems to indicate $a=1$ b arbitrary corresponds to $S^3$ unless I'm misunderstanding? (Bottom left of page 2) what you say is what I thought before reading that

Comment: They do correspond to $S^3$, but the $b = 0$ case does as well. Note that $\phi_{a, 0}(z) = (I, z^a)$ so $\phi_{a,0}(U(1)) = \{I\}\times U(1)$, so $(SU(2)\times U(1))/\phi_{a,0}(U(1)) = (SU(2)\times U(1))/(\{I\}\times U(1)) \cong SU(2)$.

Comment: @Michael_Albanese from the perspective of Dehn surgery, I had thought the ratio of the above  integers, correspond to the surgery coefficient? Is that correct? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehn_surgery

Answer (score 2):

There are some basic isomorphisms that make this much easier to see. First $U(1) \cong S^1$, which you can see be writing out the definition of $U(1)$. Second, $SU(2) \cong S^3$, the $3$-sphere, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#The_group_SU(2)). Finally there is a standard action of $S^1$ on $S^3$ with quotient $S^2$, called the [Hopf fibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration). If you represent the $3$-sphere as $SU(2)$ this action is just complex multiplication.

So topologically we have $SU(2) \times U(1) / U(1) \cong S^2 \times S^1$ if the $U(1)$ acts by the Hopf fibration.

Comment: Thank you! I am familiar with the fact that $S^3$ is a Hopf bundle for $S^1$ fibers over $S^2$ base. How would I apply that to a connected sum of several of these manifolds?           I have also looked at this from the Dehn surgery perspective, where each connected sum is integral Dehn surgery (coefficient 0) on the unlink composed of unknots in $S^3$

Comment: +1 The reason I composed it this way is that the a, b's have correspondences to hypercharge when applied towards the electroweak physics models for which the problem is ultimately intended. (if you're curious take a look at the linked paper, it's pretty decent)